# Will windows refresh launch an application much faster?

Tags: windows, c#-4.0

I have a C# console application which takes a lot of time of launch.

When I open task manager and press F5 in parallel, the application is launching much faster than it is.

What is the technical reason behind it ?

If so, can we implement the refresh logic in the code (in parallel to the main thread). I know it sounds strange, just trial and error.

Edited : The console applicaton loads lot of assmeblies using reflection (more than 400).

Please provide your inputs.

Comment: Instead of trying weird things like that why don't you try to find out why it is taking a long time to launch? Console apps doesn't take a long time to launch in general. Is your app loading a lot of assemblies during startup?

Comment: yes, its not just an console app.. It loads more than 400 dlls using reflection.

Comment: Well, that'll take some time. Any reason you need to load all of these as part of launch? I doubt task manager has any influence on this, but VS has a helper debug process that might speed up your scenario. However, that won't translate to a cold start of the app for users in general.

Comment: That's how application designed, the base architecture...What was the helper debug process??

Comment: VS launches a vshost process alongside your app, but as I said I don't believe that's the answer to your question. If startup is slow due to loading hundreds of DLLs dynamically, you need to optimize that. Perhaps you can identify a much smaller set that is needed for the launch experience and load the others later.